# Not getting data from a table because of null value of foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot

I am using mysql data table and SQL query for fetching data, I am selecting from two tables joined by one to many and many to one relationship, but if the mapped table is not having any value then I am not getting even the value of the table which I am selecting. But when I am putting foreign key then its working fine and I am data of both table.

```
@Query("SELECT LD,REC FROM LayerDetails LD JOIN LD.recipeUser REC")
public List getLayerDetails();
```

This is my SQL query when recipeUser is null then inspite of having value of Layerdetails I am not getting any values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I heaved same problem. I solved it by `LEFT JOIN` instead simple `JOIN`.

**[INNER] JOIN** - Returns only records that match in both tables

**FULL JOIN** - Returns records in both tables. If there is no match, the missing side will contain null.

**LEFT JOIN** - Returns all records from left table, with the matching records in table right (if available).

**RIGHT JOIN** - Returns all records from right table, with the matching records  in table left (if available).

[image: Explanation Venn diagram]

You can view [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Eugen, Working perfectly after using LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `JOIN` here is an inner join (which is the default if you don't use a specific join). The inner join iterates over tuples of `LayerDetails` and `RecipeUser`. However, as the field `recipeUser` is `null` in your case, it does not have a tuple for that instance of `LayerDetails`. So to also find instances of `LayerDetails`, which have no `recipeUser`, you would need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
@Query("SELECT LD,REC FROM LayerDetails LD LEFT JOIN LD.recipeUser REC")
public List getLayerDetails();
```

If you want to have more information on different `JOIN` possibilities in JPA, you could have a look at https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from for example.